# Lime survey multiple tabs not working sequentially while filling the questionare

Tags: survey, surveymonkey, limesurvey

While testing a survey by opening of different tabs. A problem is occur like
if two tabs are opened

- On first tab 3 questions have answered and next is pressed now next
  survey has proceed to next page fill questions here and next is
  pressed again now page number is three.
- At the same time on second    tab when first page of survey has
  answered on pressing next it takes    to third page not on second.

Both tabs should run survey in correct sequence values should be over write in DB if another tab changes the value

Answer (score 0):

LimeSurvey use $_SESSION to keep survey information. Then you can not open one survey in multiple tab.

You can hack config to add session id to the url : BUT https://security.stackexchange.com/a/14351

See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession#setUseTransparentSessionID-detail